# Responsive UI design for windows desktop application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

While designing a UI for web applications, we have CSS and 
html for responsive design interface.

But when designing desktop application, how can I get 
responsive design interface. I need to fit my application interface in
different size of screens e.g. desktop, laptop, tabs, etc.

How can I do this, using Visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only running on Windows, I personally would use WPF. It is a bit harder to learn but very powerful and flexible. It also enables you to separate the UI design from the UI Implementation. Designers can use Blend to design the GUI and the developers can use VS to implement it.

For desktop design as it is today (as long as it is windows :)), IMHO WPF is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

play with anchor properties of Tools.

Answer (score 0):

If limiting your app availability to Windows 8(and similiar) is not a problem, the Universal Apps are already suited with apis to fit a quarter/half/one-eight of screen. Seeing you mentioned tablets, I think it is the only way. If limiting is out of question, you may be interested in WPF, as suggested by Ned Stoyanow. There is also some projects like ModernWPF, which has responsiveness in it. Also, using a ribbon control for menu helps greatly.

Also, if I am not mistaken, you can develop Universal apps using HTML and style it via CSS.